# How to get top-terms per cluster after using k-means with TFIDF Transformer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm using the scikit-learn k-means algorithm. In my case, the input documents are term-vectors, so I used DictVectorizer and then TfidfTransformer to normalize the data:

```
dict_vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
dict_sparse_matrix =dict_vectorizer.fit_transform(doc_term_vectors)
X = TfidfTransformer().fit_transform(dict_sparse_matrix)
```

Once the k-means algorithm finishes, I would like to obtain the top terms per cluster:

```
order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = dict_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

The problem with that, is that the "top" terms are retrieved without taking into account the tf-idf weighting. I know that what I want can be achieved by using a TfidfVectorizer, however I dont have a list of strings as input, so I can't use it.